# How to capitalize the first letter of each name in an array?

Tags: c++

Here is the question:

Create a function that takes an array of names and returns an array where only the first letter of each name is capitalized.

example

capMe(["mavis", "senaida", "letty"]) ➞ ["Mavis", "Senaida", "Letty"]

And the code I wrote to answer this question:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void capme(vector<string> name)
{
    char ch;
    for(int i = 0; i < name[i].size(); i++)
    {
        putchar(toupper(name[i][0]));
        cout << name[i] << endl;
    }
}

int main()
{

   vector <string> name = {"mavis", "senaida", "letty"};
   capme(name);
   return 0;
}
```

As you can see, it prints "Mmavis", "Ssenaida", "Lletty", which is wrong. Can you guys help me in answering this question as I don't know how?

Comment: `putchar` is wrong. access the first element of the word using `std::string::operator[]`.

Comment: Your function doesn't return anything, it just prints. I'd suggest starting by writing a function that takes a single string as an argument and returns a string that's the same but with the first letter capitalized. Then use that to build your function that takes a container and returns a container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the input argument, we have two choice: make the argument mutable reference, or add a return type, here I choose the first one.

`putchar` can be used to print only one character, it recommended to use `cout` to print a string, possible solutions:

1. with traditional loop: capme
2. with [range for-loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) since c++11 : capme2
3. with stl algorithm [transform](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/transform/): capme3

Don't forget to check if the string element is empty, or you may crash while accessing the first character.

To obey the [single-responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle) (SRP), it's better to print the string vector out of the `capme` function.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void capme(vector<string>& name) {
  for (int i = 0; i < name[i].size(); i++) {
    if (name[i].empty()) continue;
    name[i][0] = toupper(name[i][0]);
  }
}

void capme2(vector<string>& names) {
  for (auto& name : names) {
    if (name.empty()) continue;
    name[0] = toupper(name[0]);
  }
}

void capme3(vector<string>& names) {
  std::transform(names.begin(), names.end(), names.begin(), [](auto& s) {
    return s.empty() ? s : (s[0] = toupper(s[0]), s);
  });
}
```

[Online demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Ga94TcM6c)

Comment: Great answer. Giving 3 different ways. Although, I'd suggest clarifying the code a little, for the OP seems to be a new programmer.

Answer (score 0):

You have used the wrong function. What you need is a replacement and not a prepend. Try using `std::string::operator[]` to access the first element of the words in the vector. This is how I would write this code:

```
std::vector<string> capitaliseInitLetter(std::vector<string> vec) {
    for (auto& word : vec) {
        word[0] -= 32; //add a check to see if the letter is already capital
    }
    return vec;
}
```

---

The above code is just an example which assumes that the input is valid. You'll have to add checks and exception handling for invalid inputs on your own. (Hint: Take a look at @prehistoricpenguin's answer)

Comment: Doesn't adding 32 make it lowercase?  You probably meant to subtract 32.  But the question doesn't say the names won't already be capitalized.  It just says "takes an array of names and returns an array where *only* the first letter of each name is capitalized."  Which probably means you need to check if it is already uppercase before subtracting 32.  And finally, does the word "only" in that phrase mean that all the other letters need to be changed lowercase if they aren't?

Comment: @JerryJeremiah, I have given an example code (although thanks for pointing out that little mistake I made :) ). OP needs to use this code to understand the logic and then add the exception handling on their own. Also, I think your interpretation of only is not exactly correct. I think it is that "only the first letter should be made capital and the rest should be kept as they are".

Answer (score 0):

You are calling [putchar()](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/putchar/) which writes a character to standard output, and in this case is printing the first letter of each string in `name` as uppercase, then you are writing the entire string to standard output immediately after.

Additionally, your function does not meet the requirements you stated above saying it should return an array where the strings have the first letter capitalized.

What you could do is change the signature of `capme()` to return a `std::vector<std::string>`, and perhaps utilize the [for_each()](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/for_each/) function to handle changing the first letter of each string in your vector then return it.

For reference:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>

std::vector<std::string> capme(std::vector<std::string> name)
{
    std::for_each(name.begin(), name.end(), [](std::string &s) {
        s[0] = toupper(s[0]);
    });
    return name;
}
```

Or as kesarling suggested, a simple for each loop:

```cpp
std::vector<std::string> capme(std::vector<std::string> name)
{
    for (auto& s : name) {
        s[0] = toupper(s[0]);
    }
    return name;
}
```

Comment: I would suggest against `std::for_each()`. We do have a for each loop available in C++ now :)